# How to return to last directory with cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can windows command line support Linux “cd -”?](https://superuser.com/questions/81755/can-windows-command-line-support-linux-cd)

Under Linux, I can use `cd -` to return to the last directory. How can I do that on Windows?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the pushd and popd commands.

- `pushd <dir>` will change directory from location a to location b
- `popd` will change directory back to directory a

Example:

```
pushd %TEMP%     // go to user's temp dir, and remember
pushd \Windows   // go to windows dir, and remember
popd             // go back one dir, in this case the temp dir
popd             // go back one more dir, in this where you were before temp
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, but using `cd..` works, thanks to @Акула (_[below answer](https://superuser.com/a/84948/643505)_)

Comment: `cd ..` goes one directory up. `pushd/popd` can be used to remember and go back the previous directory that you were at. It is often used in batch files where you want to remember the directory the user was at before starting the batch file, so you can return to it when you finish.

Answer (score 6):

Cmd.exe is an emulation layer for the old MS-DOS, commands are the same :

1. One step backward = **cd..**
2. All Backward =  **cd /**

For the others look at some Ms-Dos table around the web

Comment: This is not what cd - does.

If one is in /a/b/c/d then cd's to /a/e/f, `cd -` as a command returns you to /a/b/c/d, whereas `cd ..` moves you to /a/e and `cd /` moves you to /.

Comment: You are right i've misunderstanded the question. (What poor figure!) :-(

Comment: please remove this . cd .. goes up one level in folder hierarchy and not *backwards* in history. Also on win/dos the folder notation is backward slash (\\) not forward slash (/)

Comment: @elig, you can use either backward or forward slash nowadays, so `cd /` is valid. Just not when you use it with `pushd`, for some odd reason. But I agree it is not an answer to the question.