# cd Command Linux and Mystery Flags

Tags: linux, tcsh

Platform: `CentOS 6.2` Shell:`tcsh`

I'm playing around with `cd` for a BASH script, and noticed the wondrous [`cd -` option](https://superuser.com/questions/81755/can-windows-command-line-support-linux-cd), but was left with many questions...

1. Why the `cd -`?  Isn't this redundant with `cd ..`? 
   **EDIT** 
   [As FatalError points out, these two commands don't do the same things... so the answer is "no"]
2. Can you delve farther back into your history with `-` flag, a la in a browser?  
   e.g. When I type `cd -`, it takes me to my previous directory, but then if I enter that command again, it takes me to the directory I just came from, creating a sort of loop.  
   Is a shorthand for going back multiple levels supported?
   **EDIT**
   I realize I can go back with `cd ..`, but was hoping this could be a gateway to a less verbose deep back, e.g. `cd -3` vs. `cd ../../../` ... hopefully that clarifies what I'm asking....
   **EDIT2**
   As to the current feedback, while `..` is a special directory, I don't see a reason why the built-in `cd` to the terminal couldn't use a shorthand for `../../ ... ../` e.g. `cd ..5` or why the built-in also couldn't have a history (a la auto `pushd`/`popd`) that could be turned on and used like `cd -3`.  I get that this could be somewhat of security/privacy risk, but I don't see how it's any worst than storing a command history, which most shells/terminals do.
3. The manpage for `cd`, accessible via `man cd` and `help cd` (it's the same for either command), only lists `-L` and `-P` flags.  
   However when I type in `cd --help` it outputs `Usage: cd [-plvn][-|<dir>].`.  
   Am I right in assuming the other flags and the - (back) option are nonstandard?
4. What are the `-n` and `-v` flags for?  
   Both seem to take me back to my home directory, that's all I've been able to figure out via experimentation.

A quick read on web resources [[1]](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_cd.htm)[[2]](http://www.linfo.org/cd.html) offered just the same sort of info that the man page did and didn't answer my questions.

Note: The second Linux-centric resource above claimed `cd` only had two options (obviously not true in current `CentOS`) hence my assumption that this functionality could be non-standard.

Comment: You might be using a builtin provided by `tcsh` called `cd` and not invoking `/bin/cd` (unless you explicitly specify `/bin/cd` on the command line) - this probably accounts for the difference in behavior.  I'm not knowledgeable enough about `tcsh` to help you further, though.  Try typing `help cd` (that's for `bash`, don't know how it will work on `tcsh`...)

Comment: Just to add, executing `/bin/cd` would be pretty pointless (`cd` pretty much has to be a builtin to be useful). I'm pretty sure it only exists to satisfy some obscure POSIX requirement.

Comment: Ah interesting, you're right, this is `tcsh` specific... that's kind of odd.  I still am curious what the extra flags do.  `help cd` prints the same info as `man cd`, like I mentioned... no clue as to what the extra flags in the `tcsh` built-in are for.

Comment: Regarding 3, multilevel "`cd ..`": note that command history enables you to do `cd .. <Enter> <Up> <Enter> <Up>` and so on to quickly traverse backwards through the file tree. Perhaps I mostly find this more convenient because of my specific keyboard locale where `/` is behind the shift modifier, though.

Comment: true, but then you have like 3-5 `cd ..` littering your command history, which is less than optimal.  a `cd ..5` built in would not only be less typing and easy to implement, it'd also leave your history cleaner.  It's amazing to me that I'm possibly the first to have thought of it. :P

Comment: Thanks for your questions, but they should really be split into separate posts. Having several orthogonal questions (even if they are related to the same tool) in the same place makes for a less navigable site.

Comment: @I0b0 I wouldn't call them orthagonal, they're all related to the topic at hand.  The question is fairly detailed and cohesive in my opinion, but if not, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `cd -` is not the same as `cd ..`. The `cd -` command goes to the *previous* directory you were in. For example, if you're in `/home/bob` and then you run `cd /var/log`, then running `cd -` will take you back to `/home/bob`.  `cd ..` on the other hand, always goes to the parent directory.
2. If you want to keep a history like that, I suggest checking out `pushd` and `popd` which will let you use a "directory stack":

   ```
   user@host:/etc/init.d$ pushd /var/log
   /var/log /etc/init.d
   user@host:/var/log$ pushd /tmp
   /tmp /var/log /etc/init.d
   user@host:/tmp$ popd
   /var/log /etc/init.d
   user@host:/var/log$ popd
   /etc/init.d
   ```

   As for stepping back multiple levels in the directory tree, there's no common way that I know of. `..` isn't a feature of the shell, it's actually a special directory link in *nix that refers to the parent dir.
3. `cd` is a built in command, so it's flags and usage may vary by shell. But, in general the options to `cd` in `bash` on one system ought to be the same as on another system.
4. My `bash` shell doesn't list either of these flags... are you experimenting using `bash` or `tcsh`? If you're using `tcsh` you're essentially using a totally different command, so you probably want to run `bash` and mess with `cd` there.

**EDIT:**

According to the `tcsh` man page:

> With  -p, prints the final directory stack, just like dirs.  The -l,
>   -n and -v flags have the same effect on cd as on dirs, and they imply  -p.

(You can check the section about `dirs` if you want to read the specifics). Looks like it's basically making it print the directory stack after the command runs:

```
host:43> pushd /etc/init.d
/etc/init.d ~ 
host:44> pushd /var/log
/var/log /etc/init.d ~ 
host:45> pushd /tmp
/tmp /var/log /etc/init.d ~ 
host:46> cd -p
~ /var/log /etc/init.d ~ 
host:47> cd -v
0       ~
1       /var/log
2       /etc/init.d
3       ~
host:48> popd
/var/log /etc/init.d ~ 
host:49> cd -v
0       ~
1       /etc/init.d
2       ~
```

both show the directory stack, but `-v` seems a little easier to read. The top of the stack (element 0) is the current directory, and 1 is where you'd go if you execute `popd` once, and so on.

Comment: 1 -- yup, good point.  2 -- good thought, forgot that about `..`.. I see how that would make shorthand problematic for a true history, which could be in non-connected dirs.  3. Interesting 4. As I mention in the comment, I'm using `tcsh`... I guess I confused the issue a bit by saying I was looking to write a `bash-script`, so fixing that now...

Comment: P.S. I voted you up, but you didn't explain what those non-standard flags do in `tcsh`'s `cd` built-in, so I'm still waiting for a more complete solution.  Also it seems like `cd ..5` (go back 5 directories) and `cd -5` (go back in a directory history 5 directories) could be useful additions to the built-in shell `cd`, as I explain in my second edit.